# React ThreeJs render problem - Computed radius is NaN

Tags: reactjs, three.js

I am new to threejs and I have a problem with a stars models that I am trying to show on my screen.
The points works, but I am getting this message:

`THREE.BufferGeometry.computeBoundingSphere(): Computed radius is NaN. The "position" attribute is likely to have NaN values.`

after looking at my code and after seeing that the part that doing the problem was the stars canvas.
StarsCanvas:

```
const StarsCanvas = () => {
  return (
    <div className="w-full h-auto absolute inset-0 z-[-1]">
      <Canvas camera={{ position: [0, 0, 1] }}>
        <Suspense fallback={null}>
          <Stars />
        </Suspense>
        <Preload all />
      </Canvas>
    </div>
  );
};
```

this is the Canvas that I am using and below is the Stars component:

Stars:

```
import * as random from "maath/random/dist/maath-random.esm";
...
const Stars = (props) => {

  const ref = useRef();
  const [sphere] = useState(() =>
    random.inSphere(new Float32Array(5000), { radius: 1.2 })
  );

  useFrame((state, delta) => {
    ref.current.rotation.x -= delta / 10;
    ref.current.rotation.y -= delta / 15;
  });

  return (
    <group rotation={[0, 0, Math.PI / 4]}>
      <Points ref={ref} positions={sphere} stride={3} frustumCulled {...props}>
        <PointMaterial
          transparent
          color="#f272c8"
          size={0.002}
          sizeAttenuation={true}
          depthWrite={false}
        />
      </Points>
    </group>
  );
};
```

the useFrames is making the stars move and it is working.

the part that doing the problem is most likely the
`random.inSphere(new Float32Array(5000), { radius: 1.2 })`
it is apparently gives values that make the radius NaN (maybe after the loading?).
I am using "@react-three/fiber" and "@react-three/drei libraries

I read the docs but didn't found any solution to my problem, would like to have some help
Thanks!

Rewriting the random position and it still doesn't work.
writing a different way to showing stars

Comment: I couldn't get your example running. Where does the object `random` come from ?

Comment: It cones from maath library
import * as random from "maath/random/dist/maath-random.esm";

Comment: Maybe something to do with [computeBoundingBox default value `null`](https://threejs.org/docs/api/en/core/BufferGeometry.html) ? _"Bounding boxes aren't computed by default. They need to be explicitly computed, otherwise they are `null`. "_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found the solution!

the random function generate 5000 points.
the threejs vector takes 3 points - x,y,z from the array.
making the last z point not exist! (5000/3 -> 1666 2/3)
I needed to change to a number that is divided by 3 - 5001
making the error gone.

```
const [sphere] = useState(() =>
random.inSphere(new Float32Array(5001), { radius: 1.2 }));
```

Answer (score 0):

const sphere = random.inSphere(new Float32Array(5000), { radius: 1 });

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Answer (score 0):

i have answer for this just you need render `<StarsCanvas/>` in the `<Contact/>` like this

```
 <motion.div
        variants={slideIn('right', 'tween', 0.2, 1)}
        className='xl:flex:1   xl:h-auto md:h-[550px] h-[350px] w-4/6'
      >
        <EarthCanvas />
      </motion.div>
      <StarsCanvas />
    </div>
  );
};

export default SectionWraper(Contact, 'contact');
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why everyone else is getting a different solution on this.

I tried changing radius from `1.2` to whole number of `5` - `10` and it worked. Code section below:

```js
const [sphere] = useState(() =>
random.inSphere(new Float32Array(5000), {radius:10}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Strange, changing the radius to 5-10 didn't help, but fixing 5000 to 6000 with a radius of 1.2 solved the problem